# Transactions in MySql not working via PDO first correct query performed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a problem with transaction in mysql via PDO in PHP.

My code:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=;dbname=",'','',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true));
        try
        {
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $db->beginTransaction();
            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $sth = $db->query("INSERT INTO `list_Lists`(`status`, `createDate`,`operator`) VALUES ('0','{$date}','{$this->operator}')");
            if($sth)
            {
                $id = $db->lastInsertId();
                foreach($this->ordersNumbers as $order)
                {
                    $db->query("INSERT INTO `list_Positions`(`idLisat`, `orderNr`) VALUES ('{$id}','{$order}')");
                }
            }
            $db->commit();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            $db->rollback();
            print_r($e);
        }
```

In foreach my query have a fault. Becouse a wanted testing a tranaction - but the first INSERT despite the mistake in other INSERTS is performed.

Comment: what kind of "fault"? how do you know there was a mistake? did you see the result of print_r($e);?

Comment: In foreach query i use incorrect column name in query is idLisat but correct is idLista

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'idLisat' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\collectionLists\class\lists.class.php on line 79

Comment: Please be warned that your `INSERT` queries are widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: you need to make all tables innodb

Comment: Very thanks for your tips. Problem was tales engine, after change on innodb transactions works correct.